# Get value of textview in cardview from recycleview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecycleView` that has cards inside of it. Each card has a list of companies and prices.

In my `onBindViewHolder` I have a click event where I would like to get the price of the `TextView` in that row inside of the `Cardview`.

Every time I click I always get the value/price of the top item inside of the individual card and never get the price of the item I am clicking.

The data param of the `bindData` method is what I am using to create the list of items inside of the `Cardview`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just need to get the value of the correct `TextView` where I am clicking.

```
public class StockCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StockCardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder   {

    protected RelativeLayout mCardBodyLayout;
    protected TextView mTitleTextView; 

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mCardBodyLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.card_body);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_title); 
    }

    public void bindData(StockCategoryModel data, Context ctx) {
        this.mTitleTextView.setText(data.getCategoryName());

        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(ctx);

        int rows = data.getStockList().size();

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(ctx);

            TableLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams (TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rowParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 16);
            row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

            LinearLayout rl = new LinearLayout(ctx);
            rl.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            Integer priceColor = SharedUtilities.getColor(data.getStockList().get(r).priceChange, ctx);

            //price row
            LinearLayout priceLayout = new LinearLayout(ctx);
            priceLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            priceLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            priceLayout.setWeightSum(4);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

            final TextView price_text = new TextView(ctx);
            price_text.setTag("priceTag");
            price_text.setText(data.getStockList().get(r).price);
            price_text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
            price_text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            price_text.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
            priceLayout.addView(price_text);

            //company row
            final TextView name_text = new TextView(ctx);
            name_text.setText(data.getStockList().get(r).company); 
            name_text.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            name_text.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            name_text.setMaxWidth(700);
            name_text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            name_text.setMaxLines(1);
            name_text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);

            rl.addView(priceLayout);
            rl.addView(name_text);
            row.addView(rl);

            tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
            tableLayout.addView(row);
        }
        mCardBodyLayout.addView(tableLayout);
    }

}

private List<StockCategoryModel> mDataset;
private Context mContext;

// Constructor
public StockCardAdapter(List<StockCategoryModel> dataset, Context ctx) {
    this.mDataset = dataset;
    this.mContext = ctx;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
 }

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public StockCardAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,
                                                      int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v2) {
            final TextView textViewName = (TextView) v2.findViewWithTag("priceTag"); ;
            final String priceTag = textViewName.getText().toString();
        }
    });

    holder.bindData(mDataset.get(position), mContext);
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to set a click listener to every row separately.

**Why do you always get the first row value?**

This code,

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v2) {
        final TextView textViewName = (TextView) v2.findViewWithTag("priceTag"); ;
        final String priceTag = textViewName.getText().toString();
    }
});
```

Sets a click listener to every list item - the whole card. This means that every time the user clicks inside the card view bounds - this callback will be fired. **BUT**, who will be `v2`? It will always be the view to which we set the listener to - in this case - the whole card.

This means that every time you call `v2.findViewWithTag("priceTag");` you are searching the first child of the entire card that has the tag "priceTag" - which is the "top" item in the card.

**How to solve this issue?**

If you want to identify which child is being clicked - you will have to set a click listener to each child directly.

As an example, try this code (see *ADDED* comments):

```
public class StockCardAdapter extends 

RecyclerView.Adapter<StockCardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder   {

    protected RelativeLayout mCardBodyLayout;
    protected TextView mTitleTextView; 

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mCardBodyLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.card_body);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_title); 
    }

    public void bindData(StockCategoryModel data, Context ctx, View.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.mTitleTextView.setText(data.getCategoryName());

        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(ctx);

        int rows = data.getStockList().size();

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(ctx);

            TableLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams (TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rowParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 16);
            row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

            LinearLayout rl = new LinearLayout(ctx);
            rl.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            Integer priceColor = SharedUtilities.getColor(data.getStockList().get(r).priceChange, ctx);

            //price row
            LinearLayout priceLayout = new LinearLayout(ctx);
            priceLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            priceLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            priceLayout.setWeightSum(4);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

            final TextView price_text = new TextView(ctx);
            price_text.setTag("priceTag");
            price_text.setText(data.getStockList().get(r).price);
            price_text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
            price_text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            price_text.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
            priceLayout.addView(price_text);

            //company row
            final TextView name_text = new TextView(ctx);
            name_text.setText(data.getStockList().get(r).company); 
            name_text.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            name_text.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            name_text.setMaxWidth(700);
            name_text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            name_text.setMaxLines(1);
            name_text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);

            rl.addView(priceLayout);
            rl.addView(name_text);
            row.addView(rl);

            tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
            tableLayout.addView(row);

            // *ADDED* set the listener directly to each row
            row.setOnClickListener(listener);

        }
        mCardBodyLayout.addView(tableLayout);
    }

}

private List<StockCategoryModel> mDataset;
private Context mContext;

// Constructor
public StockCardAdapter(List<StockCategoryModel> dataset, Context ctx) {
    this.mDataset = dataset;
    this.mContext = ctx;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
 }

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public StockCardAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,
                                                      int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // *ADDED* Send the callback to the bind method
    holder.bindData(mDataset.get(position), mContext, new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v2) {
            final TextView textViewName = (TextView) v2.findViewWithTag("priceTag"); ;
            final String priceTag = textViewName.getText().toString();
        }
    }));
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

}
```

**NOTE:**

This is NOT the proper way to handle a RecyclerView - You never want to create a new object (in this case `new View.OnClickListener() {}`) inside the data binding - that will reduce performance. But this is another issue :)

Comment: This seems to be working. Thank you very much. I do not have time right now but will come back and review closer and mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The tag of textView is same in all the cases and that's why it is repeating, only the value of first item. Assign unique tag usually by concatenating `"priceTag"` with position. Make changes in your code as follows:

```
public void bindData(StockCategoryModel data, Context ctx, int position) {
 //All your code
  //..
 //...


 final TextView price_text = new TextView(ctx);
 price_text.setTag("priceTag"+String.valueOf(position));
}
```

and in your onBindViewHolder:

```
final TextView textViewName = (TextView) v2.findViewWithTag("priceTag"+String.valueOf(position)); 


holder.bindData(mDataset.get(position), mContext,position);
```

Comment: That did not work for me. I am still having the same issue.  When I click the value of position is always 0 in my onBindViewHolder

Comment: Try holder.getAdapterPosition() instead of position where position is passed as a parameter inside onBindViewHolder. Let me know if that works. I'll edit the answet accordingly then

Comment: That didnt work either. holder.getAdapterPosition is always 0 when I click.I am also having some issues with the app freezing now. Is there a better place to do the onclickevent listener? I am wondering if putting it in onBindViewHolder is causing issues?

Comment: Try putting setHasStableIds(true) inside the recyclerview constructor. A better place to put the listener is inside your Recyclerview holder. Do that and see if it works. Do let me know what works as I'm getting very curious about this as well now. :)

Comment: Looks like if I put a break point on holder.itemView.setOnClickListener the IDE freezes. I guess I just wont put a break point there.

Comment: How would I know the position in the ViewHolder?

Answer (score 0):

Find child view from Tag
please call it.

```
TextView priceTagTextView =(TextView)getViewsByTag(mCardBodyLayout, "priceTag").get(0);  



private ArrayList<View> getViewsByTag(ViewGroup root, String tag){
    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    final int childCount = root.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = root.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            getViewsByTag((ViewGroup) child, tag));
        }

        final Object tagObj = child.getTag();
        if (tagObj != null && tagObj.equals(tag)) {
            views.add(child);
        }

    }
    return views;
}
```

Comment: getViewsByTag(mCardBodyLayout, "priceTag").get(0); just returns the first element in the card. I tried this in my onBindViewHolder but my position is always 0 on click. I also tried this in my viewHolder but I do not know what to set .get(0) there.

Comment: please check it. This is changed it(getViewsByTag)
and check ArrayList<View> size.

Comment: When i try calling your updated code in viewholder i get the same issue as before. When i try it in the onBindViewHolder i get indexoutofboundsexception

Comment: I'm sorry Could you upload your source cod on github?